# Зона видимости врага

Tags: unity3d

Делаю 3D игру, создал патрулирующего врага и хотел реализовать его зону видимости при помощи коллайдера(триггер) и проверки по тегу т.е. если враг видит игрока, то игра заканчивается, а если в коллайдере(триггере) есть объект с тегом Player и объект с тегом Object, то по идее враг должен игнорировать игрока, но это почему - то так не работает, то он видит либо только игрока, либо все кроме игрока, почему?

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
        
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider col) 
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag != "Wall" && col.gameObject.tag == "Player") // если тег != стене и тег == игроку, то код выполняется
        {
            // Смерть //
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем проверять, что тег не равен стене и равен игроку, если при теге равном игроку он точно не равен стене? Почему не не обойтись одной проверкой на игрока?

Comment: Может у вас какие-то проблемы с тегами в проекте?

Comment: Вообще я это делал для проверки чтобы враг не видел игрока за стеной, но я сделал так что если в триггере уже находится тег стены и в добавок к этому в него попадает игрок, то он не умрет, т.к. скорей всего находится за стеной, да это сомнительное решение. Я изначально хотел сделать через Raycast, но столкнулся с проблемой что если на сцене будут более 1 врага, то лучи работают только у одного.